# Invalid certificate received from server xamarin.android

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

So this is driving me crazy for 1 day now. I'm trying to talk to a REST API on xamarin.android but for some reason I get this error:

```
InnerException  {Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid
certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a   at
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.RemoteValidation
(Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientContext context, AlertDescription
description) [0x00000] in :0    at
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates
(Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates) [0x00000]
in :0    at
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1
() [0x00000] in :0    at
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process ()
[0x00000] in :0    at
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage
(Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg) [0x00000] in :0    at
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback
(IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0
}   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException
```

After some research I found that this has to do with the missing certificate from the server I'm talking to (correct me if I'm wrong). So I added the SSL certificate to keychain on my Mac. I also ran the Mozilla command for installing the default certificates.

Unfortunately this still not works. On windows the connection with the API works like a charm. From what I read this is because windows got its own CA store and some default certificates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having the same issues as you do, in my case I actually managed to figure out I had a certificatename-missmatch. Something I don't know how to solve, as it's not my server I am requesting data from.

A work-around for development I used so far is to surpress all SLL, and just accept all there is using the following code:

```
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
                (
                    (srvPoint, certificate, chain, errors) => true
                );
```

or a bit shorter

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
```

However, take note that this is not THE solution to the problem, but just a work-around so you can continue developing.

I hope this helps you out, and you can get your mind of this nasty exception for now :-)

Comment: Thanks for the work around Honnes. We removed the connection to the problematic service for now. Its very strange because running it against our own servers it works just fine.

Hopefully there will be a solution to this soon.

Comment: even shorter - type inference is strong enough to deduce `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` thus `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };`